# Modal bugged because of "undefined" variable that has already been declared

Tags: javascript, variables, modal-dialog

I am going through some code to open and close modals. Everything was fine until the end. The modal is supposed to close by:

- clicking on a "Close" button
- clicking on the "ESC" key
- clicking outside the modal.

The first two went fine, but the last one was not working. When I looked into the console, I had the message that `"Uncaught ReferenceError: $modalContainer is not defined".`

`$modalContainer`, however, had been declared in the first lines of the function. It had worked through all the code and even outside of the function where it had been declared.

I found two workarounds to make it work, but they are not exactly best practices: re-declaring the same variable OR using `document.querySelector('#modal-container')` to finish the job.

```
// creates function to exhibit modal
function showModal() {
  var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container'); //selects container
    $modalContainer.classList.add('is-visible'); // add visibility class
    }
// function to hide modal
function hideModal() {
  var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container'); //selects container
  $modalContainer.classList.remove('is-visible'); //remove visibility class
}

// create event listener to show modal
document.querySelector('#modal-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  showModal('This is not a headline', 'Here is a detail');
});

    //-- show modal --
function showModal(title, text) {
  var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
  $modalContainer.innerHTML = '';
  // creates div for modal itself
  var modal = document.createElement('div');
  modal.classList.add('modal');

  // creates button to close modal and activate hideModal()
  var closeButtonElement = document.createElement('button');
  closeButtonElement.classList.add('modal-close');
  closeButtonElement.innerText = 'Close';
  closeButtonElement.innerHTML = "Close"; // new line
  closeButtonElement.addEventListener('click', hideModal); // new line

  // create H1 headline on Modal and message title variable
  var titleElement = document.createElement('h1');
  titleElement.innerText = title;

  // create <p> text on Modal and message text variable
  var contentElement = document.createElement('p');
  contentElement.innerText = text;

  //appends elements closebutton, titleand content to modal
  modal.appendChild(closeButtonElement);
  modal.appendChild(titleElement);
  modal.appendChild(contentElement);
  $modalContainer.appendChild(modal);

  // adds visibility class (?)
  $modalContainer.classList.add('is-visible');
};

// creates ESC shortcut to close modal
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');
  if (e.key === 'Escape' && $modalContainer.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
    hideModal();
  }
});

/* 
uncomment variable declaration and the modal closes as expected: with the "ESC" key, clicking on "Close" modal button and clicking outside the modal element.
*/

// var $modalContainer = document.querySelector('#modal-container');

// creates "Close" action by clicking outside modal
$modalContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  var target = e.target;
  if (target === $modalContainer) {
    hideModal();
  }
});
```

I am probably missing something simple here, but can't find an answer. Can someone enlighten me so I can see where does the issue lies? To provide extra background other than the JavaScript code, I created a Codepen with all HTML, CSS and JS there: https://codepen.io/gobbet/pen/yLBGpzy

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you declare $modalContainer it is inside a function so it's scope is limited to the parent function. In your "Close" action you are adding an event listener to $modalContainer as if it were globally declared, but it doesn't exist globally.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `$modalContainer` globaly or if it is not possible (perhabs it is created when modal opens) then you can do the following:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
  if (e.currentTarget.id == 'modal-container') { 
    hideModal(); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. It works. I left the comments on the Codepen for future users to see.